# What is it about

Tags: meaning-in-context, idioms

> ***What is it about*** people who want to clone dogs?

([Reference](https://www.psychologytoday.com/intl/blog/genetic-crossroads/201103/what-is-it-about-people-who-want-clone-dogs))

I'd like to know if "***What is it about***" is an idiom.
I can't understand what "***it***" refers to.

Comment: Usually "it" in such contexts means some kind of trend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is it about people who want to clone dogs?

"What is it about"/ "What is this about" is a standard idiom which is used before stating something that one has heard about to ask if it is true, if it exists, it really happened, etc. [Merriam Webster definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/what%27s%20this%20about)

So might be there is a trend going on about people cloning dogs (I don't know what that is supposed to mean, at all) that the author is completely unaware about. Or might be someone told him, and he is out to verify the truth of the statement.

So to answer your main question that what exactly does "it" or "this" refers to is the trend or the spoken event or scandalized event, etc.